# JDBC's SetEndToEndMetric on ADO.net

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ado.net, odp.net

Oracle's JDBC driver has a method to send piggyback metrics with every connection object. We would like to do the same with ODP.net and/or ADO.net.

I see we can receive statistics on the client: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h2ahss8(VS.80).aspx but what if I would like to send a custom statistic that my server understands.

What would be the best way to piggyback metrics to ADO.net/ODP.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the doc for what you are looking for:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/win.121/e17732/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT190

In case this link breaks someday, search the ODP.NET doc for "Client Identifier and End-to-End Tracing" and you will find these properties on the OracleConnection object:

```
Action - Specifies an action, such as an INSERT or UPDATE operation, in a module

ClientId - Specifies an end user based on the logon ID, such as HR.HR

Client info - Specifies user session information

Module - Specifies a functional block, such as Accounts Receivable or General Ledger, of an application
```